# How to convert string to float and remove char during the reading process

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The column ChangeP contains strings like this: "6.45%"
I want to convert the whole column to floats and remove '%' while in the read line so I can print and compare in the next line

I've tried this

```
df = pd.read_csv('spxweekly.csv', dtype={'ChangeP':float})
print(df.types)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.45%'

It works with this

```
bigmove = df.loc[df['ChangeP'] > "5"]
print(bigmove.ChangeP.str.replace('%', '').astype(float))
```

Some of the strings are negative and I need to convert them to negative floats as well

But I cant structure the read line properly to make it work in one line

Answer (score 0):

Use `converters` parameter with custom function for remove `%` by `strip` and cast to floats:

```
df = pd.read_csv('spxweekly.csv', converters={'ChangeP':lambda x : float(x.strip('%'))})
```

Comment: sweet thank you. For anyone else that runs into this problem in the future, this works great with the query function!!